# How configure and use Box Spout on Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4, xlsx, ioexception

I need configure and use Box Spout on Laravel 4.2, but, library does not work. I ran the command to install Composer dependencies:

```
composer require box/spout
```

But, the code not work:

```
$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX); // for XLSX files

$filePath = public_path() . "/relatorios/test.xlsx";
$writer->openToFile($filePath);

$singleRow = ['No'=>1,'Nama'=>'Bayummic','Nilai'=>11,'Nim'=>14140101];
$writer->addRow($singleRow); // add a row at a time

$writer->close();
```

Error Message:

```
[2016-12-07 17:35:38] production.INFO: D:\Projetos\Testes\LaravelQueues\public [] []
[2016-12-07 17:35:38] production.ERROR: exception 'Box\Spout\Common\Exception\IOException' with message 'Cannot perform I/O operation outside of the base folder: C:\Windows\Temp' in D:\Projetos\Testes\LaravelQueues\vendor\box\spout\src\Spout\Common\Helper\FileSystemHelper.php:130
```

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something wrong with the default temporary folder, where the XLSX file is created. You can try using `$writer->setTempFolder('PATH/TO/CUSTOM/TEMP/FOLDER');` before calling `openToFile()` to override the default location.